# Primefaces <p:spinner> with <p:ajax ... listener>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay

I have this code write in JSF2 - PrimeFaces 5.0 inside liferay 6.2 enviroment. And the listener of spinner is never fired. I also tryied to write `listener="#{managedBean.myListener()}" (see below for other way )` but this not worked. Can anyone help me?

**view.xhtml**

```
<f:view
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<h:form id="form">

<p:dataTable id="basicDT" 
             var="item" 
             value="#{managedBean.list}"
             >
    <p:column headerText="..." width="60%">
       ...
    </p:column>
     ...
     <p:column headerText="Column2" width="20%">
        <p:spinner id="mySpinner"                
                   stepFactor="1"                                    
                   min="1"
                   value="#{item.value}" 
                  >
                    <p:ajax 
                            update=":form:spinnerValue" 
                            listener="#{managedBean.myListener}" />
        </p:spinner>
    </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

     <p:outputPanel id="container">
          <p:outputLabel id="spinnerValue" value="#{managedBean.labelValue}"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

**This is the backing bean code: MyManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyManagedBean extends GenericFacesPortlet {

    private double labelValue;
    private ArrayList<MyObject> list;

    public void myListener(){
        System.out.println("Listener fired!");
        ...
    }

// getters & setter
}
```

**The problem is that the listener is never fired!**

Comment: one question: Why you are extending GenericFacesPortlet, if its not required then remove it, it may work.

Comment: As a workaround you may use `oncomplete="#{managedBean.myListener}"` instead of `listener="#{managedBean.myListener}"`

Comment: oncomplete wants client-side code...

Comment: The code looks perfectly correct if change is a default event of spinner.

Comment: I tryied the code in this example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml but this not work too. It's clear that there is another problem but I don't know it.

Comment: I think the problem is taht spinner is inside a DataTable. Can you move it outside and check this?

Comment: Already done but this not solved the problem

Comment: You are probably running into a Liferay Faces issue: [FACES-1977](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1977) or (maybe) [FACES-2007](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2007). Try the patch for [FACES-1977](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1977) and see if that fixes your issue.